Are LLMs limited by the lack of data on articulating reasoning?
My thoughts are that since LLMs can only use the data fed to it to use as it's statistical model to generate text, that in order for it to do higher level reasoning, this would only be possible if the steps of higher reasoning are articulated somewhere in the data.
Since, when a human is trying to work something out (e.g. a chess move), the thoughts are not necessarily verbal, and further these thoughts (or some close interpretation thereof) are nowhere articulated in any text that is fed to an LLM.
Thus although an LLM may be able to learn certain algorithms that are articulated (e.g. some tips on how to play chess in a chess book) that is fed to it as data, it may not be able to do independent reasoning and develop it's own algorithms, since the process of developing our own algorithms is not written anywhere on the internet, since we, as humans don't even know how we do it.
An LLM may be able to do some simple logic such as developed and articulated by Aristotle and the like. (All fire engines are red. X is a fire engine. What colour is X?) Which is basic pattern matching. Actually reasoning and developing it's own algorithms may be beyond an LLM even given all the data on the internet.
Even if the LLM where allowed to "think" by letting it talk to itself, it could only ever reason to a degree that has been articulated in the data but never to the degree that a human does subconsciously.
It seems to me, what is needed is some extra piece of machinery that complements the LLM with some non-verbal reasoning ability (like some sort of alpha-zero type ability) and some way to internally model and simulate the world.
Perhaps what is needed is some kind of internal 2D or 3D "scratchpad" that the AI can use to try out different scenarios. But such a visual reasoning machinery an never be captured (I don't believe) by any data scraped off the internet but must be augmented on to the LLM.
Do you think this argument is correct? If not, why do you think an LLM is powerful enough on it's own to do higher level reasoning?
